# How to make a php script for specific html form to send email

Tags: php, html, css, email

I have created an html form for getting an email based query, it's a slightly complex form with multiple dropdown selections. How do i create a php script to send the information received in the form to an email in the same format?

Any help with the code would be appreciated,  I have added the image as well to show how the form looks like. [Image of the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbXdv.png)

```
<form method="post" action="http://example.com/inquire" data-parsley-validate>
<div class="input">
<input required type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First name">
</div>
<div class="input">
<input required type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last name">
</div>
<div class="input big">
<input required type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
</div>
<div class="input big">
<select name="question" required>
<option value="">I would like to: </option>
<option value="Set Up a Quick Consultation" data-istravel="0">Set Up a Quick Consultation</option>
<option value="Get a Quote Within 24 hrs" data-istravel="1">Get a Quote Within 24 hrs</option>
<option value="Make a Booking (Payment instructions sent by email within 24 hrs)" data-istravel="1">Make a Booking (Payment instructions sent by email within 24 hrs)</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="extra" style="display: none">
<div class="input big">
<select name="travel_id" data-parsley-required>
<option value="" data-isgroup="0">Select a journey</option>
<option value="31" data-id="31" data-isgroup="0" data-gaevent="WTrekComfort">W-Trek in comfort and style </option>
<option value="24" data-id="24" data-isgroup="0" data-gaevent="Caiman">Refugio Ecologico Caiman</option>
<option value="32" data-id="32" data-isgroup="0" data-gaevent="Huaorani">Huaorani</option>
<option value="17" data-id="17" data-isgroup="0" data-gaevent="TMB Self Guided">Tour du Mont Blanc - Self Guided</option>
<option value="36" data-id="36" data-isgroup="0" data-gaevent="VespaTour">Florence to Rome by Vespa</option>
<option value="34" data-id="34" data-isgroup="1" data-gaevent="Great White Sharks">Dive with Great White Sharks</option>
<option value="8" data-id="8" data-isgroup="0" data-gaevent="Cappadocia To Lycia">Adventure from Cappadocia to Lycia</option>
<option value="6" data-id="6" data-isgroup="1" data-gaevent="Camino Real">Camino Real Jungle Trek</option>
<option value="18" data-id="18" data-isgroup="0" data-gaevent="MontBlanc_Guided">Tour du Mont Blanc - Privately Guided with Glacier hiking</option>
<option value="9" data-id="9" data-isgroup="0" data-gaevent="Sukau Rainforest Lodge">Sukau Rainforest Lodge</option>
<option value="12" data-id="12" data-isgroup="0" data-gaevent="Wildlife of Borneo">Endangered wildlife of Borneo</option>
<option value="11" data-id="11" data-isgroup="0" data-gaevent="WTrek_westeast">W-Trek from West to East</option>
<option value="13" data-id="13" data-isgroup="0" data-gaevent="Explora">Explora Patagonia</option>
<option value="14" data-id="14" data-isgroup="0" data-gaevent="Chaa Creek"> The Lodge at Chaa Creek</option>
<option value="15" data-id="15" data-isgroup="0" data-gaevent="Chalalan">The Uchupiamonas at Chalalan </option>
<option value="19" data-id="19" data-isgroup="0" data-gaevent="Chamonix Adventure">Best of Chamonix Adventure</option>
<option value="20" data-id="20" data-isgroup="1" data-gaevent="Reindeer Migration">Great Reindeer Migration</option>
<option value="21" data-id="21" data-isgroup="1" data-gaevent="Finnmark_west_east">Finnmark Plateau West - East Expedition </option>
<option value="22" data-id="22" data-isgroup="1" data-gaevent="Gaucho_and_Steed">Patagonia with Gaucho and Steed</option>
<option value="23" data-id="23" data-isgroup="1" data-gaevent="Coast to Coast">Journey across the Continental Divide</option>
<option value="25" data-id="25" data-isgroup="0" data-gaevent="Barranco Alto">Fazenda Barranco Alto</option>
<option value="26" data-id="26" data-isgroup="1" data-gaevent="Polar Bear and Narwhal">Polar Bear and Narwhal Safari</option>
<option value="27" data-id="27" data-isgroup="0" data-gaevent="Remota">Remota Lodge</option>
<option value="29" data-id="29" data-isgroup="0" data-gaevent="Eco Camp Lodge">Eco Camp Patagonia</option>
<option value="30" data-id="30" data-isgroup="1" data-gaevent="Eco Camp Wildlife Safari">Eco Camp Patagonia Wildlife Safari</option>
<option value="33" data-id="33" data-isgroup="0" data-gaevent="Thailand">Thailand</option>
<option value="35" data-id="35" data-isgroup="1" data-gaevent="Darien Gap">Darien Gap Expedition</option>
<option value="37" data-id="37" data-isgroup="0" data-gaevent="Kichwa Anangu">Kichwa Añangu </option>
<option value="44" data-id="44" data-isgroup="0" data-gaevent="Kackarmountains">Trekking the Kackar Mountains </option>
<option value="46" data-id="46" data-isgroup="1" data-gaevent="EverestBike">Road to Everest</option>
<option value="52" data-id="52" data-isgroup="0" data-gaevent="Kapawi">Kapawi Eco Lodge and Reserve</option>
<option value="56" data-id="56" data-isgroup="1" data-gaevent="">Hidden Tuscany Small Group Tour: From Florence to Rome</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="input nogroup">
<input data-parsley-required type="text" name="nogroup_date_begin" placeholder="Select start date" class="datepicker">
</div>
<div class="input nogroup">
<input data-parsley-required type="text" name="nogroup_date_end" placeholder="Select end date" class="datepicker">
</div>
<div class="input big group" data-id="34">
<select name="group_date[34]" data-parsley-required>
<option value="" data-isgroup="0">Select date</option>
<option value="From 2016/08/06 to 2016/08/10">From 2016/08/06 to 2016/08/10</option>
<option value="From 2016/08/11 to 2016/08/15">From 2016/08/11 to 2016/08/15</option>
<option value="From 2016/08/16 to 2016/08/20">From 2016/08/16 to 2016/08/20</option>
<option value="From 2016/08/21 to 2016/08/25">From 2016/08/21 to 2016/08/25</option>
<option value="From 2016/08/26 to 2016/08/30">From 2016/08/26 to 2016/08/30</option>
<option value="From 2016/08/31 to 2016/09/04">From 2016/08/31 to 2016/09/04</option>
<option value="From 2016/09/05 to 2016/09/09">From 2016/09/05 to 2016/09/09</option>
<option value="From 2016/09/10 to 2016/09/14">From 2016/09/10 to 2016/09/14</option>
<option value="From 2016/09/17 to 2016/09/21">From 2016/09/17 to 2016/09/21</option>
<option value="From 2016/09/22 to 2016/09/26">From 2016/09/22 to 2016/09/26</option>
<option value="From 2016/09/27 to 2016/10/01">From 2016/09/27 to 2016/10/01</option>
<option value="From 2016/10/02 to 2016/10/06">From 2016/10/02 to 2016/10/06</option>
<option value="From 2016/10/07 to 2016/10/11">From 2016/10/07 to 2016/10/11</option>
<option value="From 2016/10/12 to 2016/10/16">From 2016/10/12 to 2016/10/16</option>
<option value="From 2016/10/17 to 2016/10/21">From 2016/10/17 to 2016/10/21</option>
<option value="From 2016/10/22 to 2016/10/26">From 2016/10/22 to 2016/10/26</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="input big group" data-id="6">
<select name="group_date[6]" data-parsley-required>
<option value="" data-isgroup="0">Select date</option>
<option value="From 2016/02/13 to 2015/12/20">From 2016/02/13 to 2015/12/20</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="input big group" data-id="20">
<select name="group_date[20]" data-parsley-required>
<option value="" data-isgroup="0">Select date</option>
<option value="From 2016/04/18 to 2016/04/25">From 2016/04/18 to 2016/04/25</option>
<option value="From 2016/04/25 to 2016/05/02">From 2016/04/25 to 2016/05/02</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="input big group" data-id="21">
<select name="group_date[21]" data-parsley-required>
<option value="" data-isgroup="0">Select date</option>
<option value="From 2016/03/21 to 2016/03/29">From 2016/03/21 to 2016/03/29</option>
<option value="From 2016/04/10 to 2016/04/18">From 2016/04/10 to 2016/04/18</option>
<option value="From 2017/02/19 to 2017/02/27">From 2017/02/19 to 2017/02/27</option>
<option value="From 2017/02/12 to 2017/02/20">From 2017/02/12 to 2017/02/20</option>
<option value="From 2017/03/28 to 2017/04/03">From 2017/03/28 to 2017/04/03</option>
<option value="From 2017/04/10 to 2017/04/18">From 2017/04/10 to 2017/04/18</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="input big group" data-id="22">
<select name="group_date[22]" data-parsley-required>
<option value="" data-isgroup="0">Select date</option>
<option value="From 2016/03/03 to 2016/03/08">From 2016/03/03 to 2016/03/08</option>
<option value="From 2016/04/07 to 2016/01/12">From 2016/04/07 to 2016/01/12</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="input big group" data-id="23">
<select name="group_date[23]" data-parsley-required>
<option value="" data-isgroup="0">Select date</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="input big group" data-id="26">
<select name="group_date[26]" data-parsley-required>
<option value="" data-isgroup="0">Select date</option>
<option value="From 2016/05/19 to 2016/05/26">From 2016/05/19 to 2016/05/26</option>
<option value="From 2016/05/26 to 2016/06/02">From 2016/05/26 to 2016/06/02</option>
<option value="From 2016/06/02 to 2016/06/09">From 2016/06/02 to 2016/06/09</option>
<option value="From 2016/06/09 to 2016/06/16">From 2016/06/09 to 2016/06/16</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="input big group" data-id="30">
<select name="group_date[30]" data-parsley-required>
<option value="" data-isgroup="0">Select date</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="input big group" data-id="35">
<select name="group_date[35]" data-parsley-required>
<option value="" data-isgroup="0">Select date</option>
<option value="From 2016/03/05 to 2016/03/18">From 2016/03/05 to 2016/03/18</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="input big group" data-id="46">
<select name="group_date[46]" data-parsley-required>
<option value="" data-isgroup="0">Select date</option>
<option value="From 2016/06/27 to 2016/07/12">From 2016/06/27 to 2016/07/12</option>
<option value="From 2016/09/05 to 2016/09/20">From 2016/09/05 to 2016/09/20</option>
<option value="From 2017/09/04 to 2017/09/19">From 2017/09/04 to 2017/09/19</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="input big group" data-id="56">
<select name="group_date[56]" data-parsley-required>
<option value="" data-isgroup="0">Select date</option>
<option value="From 2016/10/29 to 2016/11/06">From 2016/10/29 to 2016/11/06</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="input big">
<input data-parsley-required type="text" name="quantity" placeholder="Number of people?">
</div>
</div>
<div class="input big">
<textarea required name="message" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="submit">
<button class="button big">Get in touch!</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: have you made any attempt to do this? If so, please add the code to your question. Thanks.

Comment: I did but it went completely wrong so it's of no use as such

Comment: Have you created the HTML for the email?

Comment: I did not understand your question, html for the email as in?
the code that i have provided is for the form in html.
Do i need to create something else in html as well?

Comment: What would you like to send in the email? If it is html then, you need to create some html to go in the email.

Comment: Robert Have a look at the image I have uploaded, it is just a basic email with some details that i need

Comment: That is not an email. That is a site.....